# Как правильно писать "вообщем"?

Tags: орфография

Слово "вообщем" как правильно писать?

Answer (score 2):

Ввиду несуществования слова "вообщем" как класса, рекомендуется заменять его на словарные:

**[вообще](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5&all=x)**

**[в общем](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC)**

в зависимости от контекста.